# Old Windows CE 5.0 device image repair

Tags: binary-analysis

I need to repair an old industrial device, based on Intel XScale PXA255 and Windows CE 5.0. It has a bootloader on NOR Flash and OS image and filesystem partitions on NAND. I've disassembled bootloader and got OS image (srec_msbin, i've dumped it from RAM, after when bootloader loaded it), and possibility to flash it to NAND through TFTP. But if I upload it to clean NAND, i'll get working system without NAND filesystem (with no application files). I can upload files through the FTP and run it with the Telnet, but after rebooting the system is clean again.
Bootloader doesn't load anything else from NAND ot RAM, only starts the kernel.

I think, that it's because there are no partitions on NAND. If I desolder NAND chip and upload RAW dump to it through a programmer, everything will work fine. But i want to findout how to repair the system without soldering.

How can I create NAND partitions? I found BSP from Toradex for their single board computer, that uses PXA255 CPU, but i can't find BSP for my single board PC (compulab CM-X255).
Can I simply create an application to create partitions?